# How did Whiplash know that Tony Stark is going to the racing track?

Tags: plot-explanation, marvel-cinematic-universe, iron-man-2

In [***Iron Man 2*** (2010)](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1228705/), Whiplash (the villain) enters as a track marshal during a race on the Grand Monaco Racing Track, unleashing his weapons on Tony Stark when he’s most vulnerable.

[image]

But, Tony only decided to race the Stark car minutes before the race, which Whiplash couldn’t have known.

Was he able to predict that it was going to happen or is he that lucky?
Then, how could Whiplash come so prepared without knowing that?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

He doesn't. All he knows is that Stark will be there.

Whiplash's aim is not necessarily to confront Stark directly, but to humiliate him by attacking the race. showing that Stark's technology is not unique to him, to crack the world's confidence in Stark so that the government will have no choice but to step in to bring him down.

Stark choosing to drive the car, thus allowing Vanko to attack him directly, to "make him bleed", as he put it, is merely a very useful bonus.

Comment: I'm not so sure; I think he was probably intending to attack Tony directly. He seemed to wait until Tony was almost to his position to step out onto the track and start slicing up cars. He likely intended to confront him wherever he was, and only stepped onto the track because Tony hopped in a car.

Comment: It's likely that Vanko assumed that attacking the race would draw out Iron Man to confront him in some capacity. That capacity simply wound up being that Tony himself was participating in the race!

Answer (score 16):

He knows that Stark is an egomaniac and he can't go to such a prestigious race meeting and sit by idly and not race.

It was pretty inevitable that he'd get into a car and drive, so it was a pretty safe bet.

Knowing Tony Stark, this shouldn't have come as a surprise to anyone.

Whiplash also has an ego, hence disguising himself as a race marshal and attacking Stark in the middle of the race-track when he could easily have found a more discrete place and done the job properly.

Comment: Good answer, and even if Tony *hadn't* entered the race himself attacking the race would almost certainly have drawn him out to respond.